# loop to exit the programm

Tags: c#, loops

I'm trying to make a loop to understand if the user wants to continue executing the prgramm again or not.
I would like to write a loop who asks him again the question if he writes something else than yes or no

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter un number : ");

                int day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                int dayToTest = (day % 7);

                switch (dayToTest)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Monday");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Tuesday");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Wednesday");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Thursday");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Friday");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Console.WriteLine("Saturday");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        Console.WriteLine("Sunday");
                        break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(" would you like to reexecute the programmn? yes or no");
                string decision = Console.ReadLine();

                if (decision.ToLower() == "no")
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    while (decision.ToLower() != "yes")

                }



            }

        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Probably unrelated: x % 7 is in [0..6] not [1..7].

Comment: When I write CLI tools, I tend to use `ReadKey` for yes/no questions, so the user only has to type "y" or "n" and it doesn't matter if that's y or Y or n or N ...

Comment: What is your issue? The code looks good to me, you just need to remove the `else` block with the `while` loop.

Comment: `while (decision.ToLower() != "yes")` scrap that whole `else` block, then it should run.

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance to improve your future questions. As you noticed there are comments about code that is not related to the question (like @Fildor one about *potential* misunderstanding between module operator and of [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)) . Scoping code to just the one that shows the problem helps to keep noise comments to minimum (and avoid trolling when one *accidently* posts code with SQL injection for example).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `else` block. That should do what you need.

Comment: " write a loop who asks him again the question if he writes something else than yes or no" - how removing a loop altogether would help with implementing a loop?